# How long does it take for the app to time out and exit the conversation

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

How long does it take for the google assistant agent to timeout and end/leave the conversation?

I configured a chat bot with `actions-on-google` where

1. The GA would ask user to choose which product to buy from a List.
2. Then the user locked the phone's screen
3. After a few minutes, the user reactivates google assistant again
4. User selects one of the product from the list by scrolling up the history
5. The transaction proceeds

I expected the app to `exit` the conversation after a certain duration, which then start a new session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The session stays alive for 10 minutes. So, if you resume conversation within 10 minutes then it will continue in the same session.

As per my testing on Google Assistant and Simulator, if the conversation is paused for more than 10 minutes then the conversation ends and app exits.

Answer (score 0):

5 seconds.

Source: [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/conversation-webhook)

("Your response must occur within about 5 seconds or the Assistant assumes your fulfillment has timed out and ends your conversation.")

Comment: Thats the my expectation as well, but its not happening. It doesn't end even after 5 seconds. I'm able to resume the conversation even after i locked the phone for awhile.

Comment: This 5 seconds limit is for webhook response. If response from webhook isn't received within 5 seconds then conversation will end.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a 5 second limit to receive the response, is there a limit to how long the response can be? We want to access longer form responses and then (hopefully) process the text response

Answer (score 0):

It's actually 10 seconds or that's what [this](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/data/google-assistant-legacy.pdf) says.

I don't know if it's the same time for legacy actions or conversational actions.