# Is there a maximum length or amount of time that a user can respond for (in response to an Action on Google intent)

Tags: actions-on-google

I see there is a limit that a user has to respond by before the conversation ends:

```
"Your response must occur within about 5 seconds or the Assistant assumes your fulfillment has timed out and ends your conversation."
```

[How long does it take for the app to time out and exit the conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54324632/how-long-does-it-take-for-the-app-to-time-out-and-exit-the-conversation/54775258#54775258)

But is there a maximum that a user can respond for (type voice)? We want to allow for longer responses (and then access the response text).

Ideally we would like an unlimited response time and the ability to access the raw input (type voice) when received

It would be excellent if we could access the audio from the user's response, but as I understand that is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

As I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54741538/google-assistant-identify-audio-clip-and-take-an-action-based-on-that), you can't have access to the raw audio recordings of interactions with your actions as of now. You only get access to the transcription of the user's utterance.

The quote you've supplied:

> "Your response must occur within about 5 seconds or the Assistant assumes your fulfillment has timed out and ends your conversation."

isn't about the user's response. **Your** webhook fulfillment must complete in 5 seconds, otherwise, your system persona will time out.

As far as the length of users prompt goes; if the user doesn't say anything it will trigger a [no-input](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/reprompts) prompt (on smart speakers) or just close the mic (on smartphones) in around 8 seconds. (I don't know if there's an official resource that proves 8 seconds, this is just my experience)

But once the user starts speaking, it will keep listening until the user stops talking. So you can theoretically have a long prompt from the user. However, I wouldn't recommend this since it would be a terrible user experience if you look at it from a conversation design stand point.